# Prevent submit until all required fields (input,select..) are populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How can I prevent my form from submitting until all required fields are populated? Required fields could be `input`, `select`, etc.

Below is my current code which is not working. Basically after I click on the submit button I would like to  iterate through each field in the form which has tag='required' and if all fields are populated/selected then allow form submit.

Thanks.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function (e) {
    var submit = false;
    var count = 0;
    $('#Form input, #Form select').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $('#' + id).val();
        var tagValue = $('#' + id).attr('tag');
        var isDisabled = $('#' + id).is(':disabled');

        if (isDisabled == false) {
            if ($('#' + id).is(':visible')) {
                if (tagValue == 'required') {
                    if (id == 'email') {
                        validateEmail('#' + id);
                    }
                    if (id == 'phone') {
                        validatePhone('#' + id);
                    }
                    if ($('#' + id).hasClass("currency")) {
                        validateCurrency('#' + id);
                    }
                    if ($('#' + id).is('select')) {
                        if (value == '' || value == 'Unknown' || value == 'unassigned' || value == null) {
                            $('#' + id).css({
                                'border': '1px solid #F70D1A'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (value == "") {
                        $('#' + id).css({
                            'border': '1px solid #F70D1A'
                        });
                    }
                    if (value == '' || value == 'Unknown' || value == 'unassigned' || value == null) {
                        submit = false;
                    } else {
                        submit = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (!submit) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `return false` to prevent form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than attaching this event to the button click, you should attach it to the form on submit:

```
$('#Form').on('submit', function (e) {
  //-- your current code should work fine, put it here
});
```

I went ahead and cleaned up your method:

```
$("#Form").on('submit', function (e) {
    var submit = true;
    //-- use find+filter to reduce the set of matched elements
    $(this).find('input, select').filter('[tag="required"]:visible:enabled').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            value = $this.val();
        //-- switch for unique flags
        switch ($this.attr('id')) {
            case 'email': validateEmail($this); break;
            case 'phone': validatePhone($this); break;
        }
        //-- continue parsing non-unique flags
        if ($this.hasClass('currency')) validateCurrency($this);
        if (!value || value === 'Unknown' || value === 'unassigned') {
            $this.css('border', '1px solid #F70D1A');
            submit = false;
        }
    });
    if (!submit) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Things to note:

1. I removed all of the unnecessary ID-based lookups.  This is a huge performance hit, and should be reduced to a single `$(this)` lookup which you should reuse.
2. I am currently passing `$this` to each validate method, so they will have to be updated accordingly.
3. Rather than iterating through all select/input fields, I reduced the matched elements first, cutting down on unnecessary code.
4. I simplified your logic to the best of my understanding based on the code provided.
5. I switched the method used on the `submit` flag.  It now starts out as valid and will be set to false if any item fails the check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Form').on('submit', function (e) {
  $.each(this.find("[tag='required']"),function(i,item)
{
validation logic goes here.
 ....
}
)});
```